# How to get values of all sequences using currval?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sequence, currval

In example: have 3 sequences (`seq1, seq2, seq3`) and I would like make one query showing their name and their current value value?

The basic syntax is

```
select schema.seq_name.currval from dual
```

But how to show value of all of them?

Comment: Please, describe what do you mean by "show value all of them". Why `schema.sequence_name.currval` is not sufficient for you? And please show your current code

Comment: schema.sequence_name.currval is sufficient for me, but how to use this syntax when I have 9999... sequences? Do I have to use this sintax for every sequence?

Comment: One also begins to wonder what is the business problem being addressed . . .  See [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`user_sequences`](https://docs.oracle.com/search/?q=user_sequences&category=database&product=en%2Fdatabase%2Foracle%2Foracle-database%2F21) data dictionary view such as

```sql
SELECT s.sequence_name, s.last_number AS curr_value
  FROM user_sequences s
 WHERE s.sequence_name IN ('SEQ1','SEQ2','SEQ3')
```

as long as those sequences are in your current schema. Otherwise, that might be replaced by `all_sequences` or `dba_sequences` depending on the situation or your need.

Comment: Is there possibilities not use any tables like 'user_sequences' and take vale only from currval?

Comment: you can consecutively execute `seqxxx.currval` after executing `seqxxx.nextval` at least once for the current session @Ron , but you'll get a different number after executing `seqxxx.nextval` . So, the answer is **No**

Comment: @Ron - `last_number` gives you last cached number (it's essentially a number saved to disk as a safe place to restart after a restart or crash, to ensure a value still can't be reissued), so it might be higher than the last number actually issued by any `nextval` call. But that might be close enough for you. And if you're using RAC, `currval` shown in a session in one instance might be lower than a value already issued on another instance.

Comment: _"Is there possibilities not use any tables like 'user_sequences'"_  - give then other things you've said, you don't want to hard-code a list of all of your sequences.  If that is the case, then the answer is "no".  If you don't want to hard-code all of the sequence names, then the only alternative is to get them from a data dictionary table.

Answer (score 0):

In spite of my deep reservations about why you would even need to do this, I tried to put together a pl/sql procedure as a demo - partly just to challenge myself.  When I ran into an issue that I thought would be simple, just needing a fresh pair of eyes, I posted on OTN.  While they addressed my coding issue, one reply summed up your problem:

you can not select currval without calling nextval. currval is the function that returns last used sequence value via nextval function on your session.